How to play a YouTube video via url in tkinter?
I'm trying to play a video from YouTube url in customTKinter.
The only solution i find by now using embedded youtube link is this:
import customtkinter
from tkinterweb import HtmlFrame  # Import HtmlFrame to use the embedded browser
import pytube
from pytube import extract

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.visualisation_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.visualisation_frame.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

        self.youtubeframe = HtmlFrame(self.visualisation_frame)  # Use HtmlFrame to display the YouTube video
        self.youtubeframe.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=(20, 5))

    # def update_url(self, url):
        video_embed_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6Ejga4kJUts"
        self.youtubeframe.load_website(video_embed_url)  # Update to load the embedded video


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

Tihs code runs, but there is a message on a place for video visualisation:

An error occurred.
Unable to execute JavaScript.

Do you have some solution of this task?
Thank you.

HtmlFrame probably emulates a web browser inside a tkinter.Frame. The error is telling you that JS is disabled inside the emulator. I suggest going through the docs and looking at how/if it's possible to turn on JS.

Looked at the GitHub page for tkinterweb and it says that "Javascript is not supported at the moment".

Yeah, i saw also the GItHub Repo and is really written: "Javascript is not supported at the moment". Sameone to have other option to play a YouTube video in Tkinter?

@r_b You can download the video using a library like pytube and then display it. For the actual displaying, I suggest embedding a VLC player in a tkinter frame. Alternatively you can drop tkinter and switch to a more modern GUI library

You can try tkwebview2.

@TheLizzard yeah i think about that option too, but everythinme i should download file, will sloww down the app.

https://www.trycatchdebug.net/news/1317587/youtube-video-playback-with-custom-tkinter

I found this https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/tree/master/examples

@toyotaSupra - "github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/tree/master/example" .
Yeah, i also try "tkVideoPLayer" , but it play only video, without audio and i have problem installing "tkVideoPLayer" with Python > 3.10.

Here is link: https://www.makeuseof.com/python-video-media-player-how-to-build/

@toyotaSupra this is also playing a local video :(
